# cant start browser from service in android

Tags: android

Hello I am trying to start the android browser from a service using this code:

```
protected void showBrowser(){

    String url = "http://www.google.com";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    this.startActivity(i);
}
```

but this doesn't seem to work! the browser is never started and using log the execution stops when the startActivity is called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might also need:

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. I think this comes from an official android tutorial, so probably you've seen it. So just use this snippet and it should work.

```
 public void openBrowser(View view){
      Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://google.com"));
       startActivity();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but this didnt do the trick either, as dhaag23 mentioned it needs the extra intent falg.

Comment: I wonder why it needs the flag? Well if it works now it's good. But I don't get why it's needed for you, but not for me..